# Prevent child p tag from expanding when parent is expanding

Tags: css, sass, css-animations

I am working on an HTML and CSS code and trying to prevent a child div text to expand when the parent expands. I want the child div to remain its own width.

I tried to add a fixed width for the child div but it is not responsive. I tried to use scaleX(), but it is not working.

HTML befor expand

```
<div class="parent col-2">
<div class="child"><p>some long text</p></div>
</div>
```

HTML after expand

```
<div class="parent col-3">
<div class="child"><p>some long text</p></div>
</div>
```

```
<style>
 .parent {
 transition: flex 0.5s ease-in-out;
 }
</style>
```

I expect the child div to remains the same width even when the parent is being expanded.

UPDATE

[code](https://codepen.io/msbir/pen/VJzMPW)

When clicking the button, it expands the parent div and the text inside the child div is being expanded to (obviously). I want to keep the child div text width - no to expand - and only the parent div to expands.

- Another way that I try is to prevent the child to be affected by the parent transition.

Comment: Insert a snippet or fiddle to get a clear idea. Give the child a max width rather than giving a fixed width.

Comment: have you tried max-width property?

Comment: @JinuKurian Hi updated the question with a code sample and explanation

Comment: @Codesigner The problem with max-width is that on different screens the width of the text is different, so by setting `max-width ` the text will still expand on different screens. Added a code sample

Comment: for that you can use media queries

Answer (score 0):

**max-width, min-width, width** -> together are useful in the child element

**display: block or display: inline-block** -> if your element has a default **display: inline**

**box-sizing: border-box** -> if your element does not fit just like you want it, you may want to try this one

*Don't forget to read documentation about these props, hope this helped you*

```css
.child {
  max-width: 640px;
  width: 100%;
  min-width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent col-3">
  <div class="child"><p>some long text</p></div>
</div>
```

Comment: When setting max-width the child can go out of the parent width